# Removing Null nested fields in Django Serializer --- or how to iterate with Null?

Tags: reactjs, django, webpack, django-rest-framework

This issue I am having is likely a React iteration problem but I think taking care of it at the root inside Django will be more efficient instead of on the front end.

**Possible remedies**:

1. ternary operation to conditionally display objects and parameters if not null
2. remove null fields from response to avoid needing to do ternary operation through django itself

Although, in the first place, I cannot seem to be able to iterate through my response.

I have a double nested serializer:

**Models**:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class VideoProduct(models.Model):
    ...

class ImageProduct(models.Model):
    ...

class ProfileProduct(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video_product = models.ForeignKey(VideoProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    image_product = models.ForeignKey(VideoProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('profile', 'video_product')
        unique_together = ('profile', 'image_product')
```

**Views.py**:

```
class VideoProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = VideoProduct.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideoProductSerializer

class ImageProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ImageProduct.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideoProductSerializer

class ProfileProductsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ProfileProduct.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileProductsSerializer

class ProfileBySlug(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileBySlugSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.request.query_params.get('slug', None)
        queryset = Profile.objects.filter(slug=slug)
        if slug is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(slug=slug)
        return queryset
```

**Serializers**:

```
class VideoProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VideoProduct
        fields = ['id', 'price']

class ImageProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageProduct
        fields = ['id', 'price']

class ProfileProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    video_product = VideoProductSerializer(read_only=True)
    image_product = ImageProductSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProfileProduct
        fields = ['id', 'video_product', 'image_product']
    
class ProfileBySlugSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile_products_set = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_profile_products')

    def get_profile_products(self, profile):
        qs = ProfileProduct.objects.filter(profile=profile)
        serializer = ProfileProductsSerializer(instance=qs, many=True)
        return serializer.data

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'description', 'slug', 'image', 'status', 'profile_products_set']
```

The issue is that a ProfileProduct will only have one association to either a video_product or image_product but my responses are like this:

API Request:

```
axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/profile/`, {
  params: {
    slug: this.state.slug,
  }
})
  .then(res => {
      this.setState({ profile: res.data.results[0] });
      this.setState({ products: res.data.results[0].profile_products_set });
....
```

Entire response:

```
[{…}]
0:
    description: "Description"
    id: 1
    profile_products_set: Array(2)
      0:
        video_product: {id: 1, price: "0.00", status: true}
        image_product: null
        __proto__: Object
      1: {image_product: {…}, video_product: null}
      length: 3
      __proto__: Array(0)
    title: "Admin Title"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

I set the state for profile_products_set  with:`this.setState({ products: res.data.results[0].profile_products_set })`

**Now when I go to iterate within React:**

```
  { this.state.products.map(product =>
    <div>
      <li>{product.id}</li>
      <li>{product.price}</li>
    </div>
  )}
```

It is blank with only bullet points.

As mentioned above, how can I one iterate over this and display it on the front end, and then if possible, remove the null fields from the response all together to avoid needing to do and ternary operations based on the product type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_representation` to override the serialization. You can then remove the entries with `None` value.

```
class ProfileProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    video_product = VideoProductSerializer(read_only=True)
    image_product = ImageProductSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProfileProduct
        fields = ['id', 'video_product', 'image_product']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation()
        return {k: v for k, v in data.items() if v is not None}
```

Comment: `data = super().to_representation(instance)`
you should pass argument.